# Offline ReactJS dev environment

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have an intranet with absolutely no internet connection and I'm trying to set up a ReactJS development environment with Babel and Webpack.

All this requires NodeJS but as I have no internet connection I would not be able to have it download any packages.

Is there a way to manually download all packages and install them on the offline machine?

Maybe download on another machine and copy everything?

Or is there an alternative which doesn't require npm?

I'm very new to this so any help or pointers would be helpful.

So far I spent hours in fruitless Google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to work offline it should be fine if you copy the `node_modules` directory from another project. Just be sure that you're copying the same dependencies and versions.

Answer (score -3):

1.) Use your mobile phone to get internet. Setup a hotspot.

https://www.androidauthority.com/mobile-hotspot-android-hotspot-android-customization-631280/

2.) Setup your project at home and copy/paste the folder